# How to better visualize weight?

Tags: bones, weight-painting, vertex-weights

Do I really have to click through every bone to see what causes a vertex to move? Isn't there a better way to see what bones affect what area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a whole area (several vertices) you can switch to *Weight Paint* mode and select each vertex group in the *Vertex Groups* list, or select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, select each bone (maybe that's what you're already doing).

For a single vertex you can select it and in the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weights*, you can see what vertex group(s) this vertex is assigned to:

[image]

With the default setting some vertices that have a very low influence will appear blue and will be confused with zero weight, so, if you want to be able to see the areas that have zero weight, enable the option in the *Viewport Overlays* panel, and zero weight will appear black:

[image]